# Finding uniques integers in an array

Tags: java, arrays, logic

i have an array of integers like this one :
A={1,1,4,4,4,1,1}

i want to count the each number once , for this example the awnser is 2 becuase i want to count 1 once and 4 once
i dont want to use sorting methods
i am unable to find a way to solve it using java.
i did this but it gives me 0

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[] = { 1,1,4,4,4,4,1,1};
    System.out.print(new Test4().uniques(a));
}

public int uniques(int[] a) {
    int unique = 0;
    int tempcount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                tempcount++;
            }
        }
        if (tempcount <= 2) {
            unique=a[i];
        }
        tempcount = 0;
    }
    return unique;
}
```

the purpose of the question is to understand the logic of it but not solving it using ready methods or classes

Comment: any effort from you?

Comment: Is there a bound on the values the array can contain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should work. I guess this might be not the most elegant way, but it is pretty straightforward and uses only simple arrays. Method returns number of digits from array, but without counting duplicates - and this I believe is your goal.

```
public int uniques(int[] a) {
    int tempArray[] = new int[a.length];
    boolean duplicate = false;
    int index = 0;
    int digitsAdded = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++) {
            if (a[i] == tempArray[j]) {
                duplicate = true;
            }
        }
        if(!duplicate) {
            tempArray[index] = a[i];
            index++;
            digitsAdded++;
        }
        duplicate = false;
    }
    //this loop is needed if you have '0' in your input array - when creating temp 
    //array it is filled with 0s and then any 0 in input is treated as a duplicate
    //again - not most elegant solution, maybe I will find better later...
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if(a[i] == 0) {
            digitsAdded++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return digitsAdded;
}
```

Comment: look at my edit, I added another loop at the end. comment in code will explain why

Answer (score 1):

if restricted to only arrays, consider trying this:

Lets Take a temporary array of the same size of orignal array, where we store each unique letter and suppose `a` is your orignal array,

```
int[] tempArray= new int[a.length];
int tempArraycounter = 0;
bool isUnique = true;
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    isUnique = true;
    for (int j = 0; j < tempArray.length; j++)
    {
        if(tempArray[j] == a[i])
            isUnique = false;
    }
    if(isUnique)
    {
       tempArray[tempArraycounter] = a[i];
       tempArraycounter++;
       isUnique = false;
    }
}
```

now `tempArraycounter` will be your answer ;)

Comment: I am afraid it will not work properly. `tempArray.length` will return size of `a.lengt`h. Its size will always `be a.length`.

Comment: oops! good point.. we can use `tempArraycounter` alternatively. Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: i tryed it it will not return the uniqueness i mean 
please test it if you can

Comment: @user309666 i missed a line. now test. it will work. have fun ;)

Answer (score 1):

Okay first of all in your solution you are returning the `int unique`, that you are setting as the value that is unique `a[i]`. So it would only return 1 or 4 in your example.

Next, about an actual solution. You need to check if you have already seen that number. What you need to check is that for every number in the array is only appears in front of your position and not before. You can do this using this code below.

```
public int uniques(int[] a) {
    int unique = 1;
    boolean seen = false;

    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                seen = true;
            }
        }
        if (!seen) {
            unique++;
        }
        seen = false;
    }
    return unique;
}
```

In this code you are iterating over the number you have seen and comparing to the number you are checking (`a[i]`). You know that for it to be unique you cant have seen it before.

Comment: this will return the count of non repeated integers which is 0 in my example i want to return 2 in my example

Comment: I had misunderstood the question. I edited the the code. try now

Answer (score 1):

I see two possible solutions:

- using set

  ```
  public int unique(int[] a) {
      Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
      for (int i : a) {
          set.add(i);
      }
      return set.size();
  }
  ```
- using quick sort

  ```
  public int unique(int[] a) {
      Arrays.sort(a);
      int cnt = 1;
      int example = a[0];
      for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
          if (example != a[i]) {
              cnt++;
              example = a[i];
          }
      }
      return cnt;
  }
  ```

My performance tests say that second solution is faster ~ 30%.

Answer (score 0):

Try Following code:

```
int test[]={1,1,4,4,4,1,1};
Set<Integer> set=new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0;i<test.length;i++){
    set.add(test[i]);
}
System.out.println(set);
```

**Output :**

```
[1, 4]
```

At the end `set` would contain unique `integers`.

Comment: im restricted to arrays

Comment: any dont want to use sets or any wierd thing

Comment: Why is set weird? And you can anyway convert set back to `int` array.